# XSS prevention on CDN hosted scripts like jQuery

Tags: javascript, cdn, xss, spoofing

[Edited:]
If a client visiting my website which serves jQuery over Microsoft's CDN network gets his/her DNS spoofed with the attacker mimicking Microsoft's CDN. In such a case, in theory the attacker should be able to run arbitrary javascript code.

Is there any way to prevent this occurrence? Or should I simply stop hotlinking CDN servers?

Comment: I am not an expert, but isn't Google serving these files via HTTPS (SSL) to prevent such attack?

Comment: @Tomasz, Yes they are, however in case I use Microsoft's CDN would my theory be valid. Microsoft serves it via HTTP [http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.2.min.js](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.2.min.js)

Comment: I you want to avoid the result of spoofing using a CDN which deliver over HTTPS seems the only reasonable solution (as long as the CA is not compromised, as it happened at least once)

Answer (score 1):

The standard XSS prevention mechanisms apply, but in this case, since it's a CDN, you probably don't have very much control over the server, so about the best you can do is to only use CDNs over SSL.

That said, if the victim's DNS is compromised already, they likely have *many* other issues, particularly with high-value sites like Banks, or large-target sites like Facebook that more people are likely to use.